# Math rescale problem in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

So, I have to resize a shape, where I want one of the components of this shape to be of a precise width. That's easy to do, the hard part is then rescale also the other components of the original shape to match... I figured out which steps I should go through, but have no clue about the last one of them.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You are right, simple math :-)

If 10,739 is the 100%, 5 is:

```
5 ✕ 100 ÷ 10,379 = 46,56
```

Select the whole shape, double click the Scale Tool and scale it 46,56 %

Comment: The real problem isn't finding that percentage, but the overall percentage. That percentage works if I scale the rectangle and the trapezoid individually, but you have to consider that they are merged and I need to scale them together as a single object, otherwise I would lose their relative position by scaling them individually.